# Swift-XCode - How to let Text Field have set values the user can choose from?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I understand how the normal text field works where the user can input their own text, but is there a way where the user clicks the `text field` and it comes up with some options, such as "Hello", "Bye", and "Goodnight"?

It's sort of like a placeholder with more options, and the placeholder really isn't in effect in this because when the user clicks the text field, the options pop up for text to select, and the user can select the text and that text will be used in the text field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPickerView) and the `inputView` property of [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView)

Implement the methods like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var dataObject : [String] = ["Hello","Bye","Good Night"];

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.delegate   = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        self.textField.inputView = picker
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1;
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.dataObject.count;
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
    {
        return self.dataObject[row];
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        self.textField.text = self.dataObject[row];
        self.textField.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```